# ocgx2: Multiple Choice Questions up to three automatic trials

Tags: ocgx2

This question is a following of the two clever and efficient answers linked below to elaborate semi-interactive quizzes/MCQ with ocgx2 (OCG/OCMG).

(1) [ocgx2: verify and reset of Multiple Choice Questions with OCGs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490706/ocgx2-verify-and-reset-of-multiple-choice-questions-with-ocgs)

(2) [ocgx2, xparse, expl3: splitting comma separated OCMD/OCGs lists of arguments for references automation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493987/ocgx2-xparse-expl3-splitting-comma-separated-ocmd-ocgs-lists-of-arguments-for)

The next step I want to deal with is to allow automatically three trials to the user each time he/she click on the check button (see the layout of the result without cosmetics). At the third step, the points are assigned. For the moment being, I am able to on one hand, have the correct/wrong quiz proposals with the OCMD layers, and on the other hand, a set of three symbols related to the trial number (OCG layers). The idea is to mix the two orientations.

After many tests, with nested or not environments, I must admit that I am lost... I certainly don't understand everything about the power of OCG/OCMG. Therefore, is this approach feasible? Intuitively I think so but if yes, how to solve such an issue?

I am also aware of the PDF viewers limitations:

(3) [Tikz & OCG: make button cycling through different layers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519226/tikz-ocg-make-button-cycling-through-different-layers)

I do hope that the new (2019) OCMD layers for LaTeX could be a friend...

[image]

*MWE*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{quizquestion}
\newcounter{mcqproposal}
\newcounter{mcqquiztotal}
\newcounter{trialnumber}

\newlength{\quizcheckboxwidth}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{quizquestion}{ m m }%
  {
    \stepcounter{quizquestion}%
    \let\mcqproposal\mcqproposalMultiple%
  }
  {
    \mcqcheck{#1}{#2}%
    \hspace{0.1\linewidth}%
    \mcqresetcheck
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mcqproposalMultiple}{ m }{%
  % Syntax − #1 = proposal/statement
  \parbox[t]{16pt}{%
    \hspace*{2pt}%
    \quizMultipleButton{mcqproposalref.\thequizquestion.\themcqproposal}%
  }%
  \parbox[t]{\linewidth-16pt}{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\quizMultipleButton}{m}{%
  % Syntax − #1: choice id for answering proposal
  % Action on click: toggle myself (choice layer), hide verification layer
  \stepcounter{mcqproposal}%
  \stepcounter{mcqquiztotal}%
  \setlength{\quizcheckboxwidth}{\widthof{\faIcon[regular]{square}}}%
  \makebox[\quizcheckboxwidth][c]{%
    \actionsocg{#1}{}{check.\thequizquestion}{\faIcon[regular]{square}}%
  }%
  \begin{ocg}{#1}{#1}{off}% choice layer
    \hspace*{-\quizcheckboxwidth}%
    \makebox[\quizcheckboxwidth][c]{\textcolor{green!60!black}{\faCheckSquare}}%
    \hspace*{-\quizcheckboxwidth}%
    \makebox[\quizcheckboxwidth][c]{\faIcon[regular]{square}}%
  \end{ocg}%
}

%%% check button

\NewDocumentCommand{\askreplymcqArgsIdsCheck}{m}{%
  mcqproposalref.\thequizquestion.#1%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \askreplymcqcheck_process_list:Nn #1 #2
  {
    % clear the sequence
    \seq_clear:N #1
    % cycle through the arguments, storing "\mcqArgsIds{<arg>}" in the sequence
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
      {
        % Here :Nx instead of :Nn ensures that \askreplymcqArgsIds
        % is actually evaluated instead of passed as-is
        \seq_put_right:Nx #1 { \askreplymcqArgsIdsCheck{##1} }
      }
  }

\seq_new:N \l_correct_seq
\seq_new:N \l_wrong_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \askreplymcq__check:nn #1 #2
  {\showocg{check.\thequizquestion}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw] (checkbutton) {\strut Check};%
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    \begin{ocg}{check.\thequizquestion}%
      {check.\thequizquestion}{off}% verification layer
      \makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \begin{ocmd}{\Not{\And{#1,\Not{\Or{#2}}}}}% "wrong" layer (OCMD)
          \hspace*{0.25em}%
          \raisebox{5pt}{\textcolor{red!60!black}{\faTimes}}%Wrong.
        \end{ocmd}%
      }%
      %\makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \begin{ocmd}{\And{#1,\Not{\Or{#2}}}}% "correct" layer (OCMD)
          \hspace*{0.25em}%
          \raisebox{5pt}{\textcolor{green!60!black}{\faCheck}}%Correct.
        \end{ocmd}%
      %}
    \end{ocg}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\actionsocg{trialstep1}{}{trialstep2,trialstep3}{\textcolor{black}{\faCircle}}}%
    \begin{ocg}{trialstep1}{trialstep1}{off}% choice layer
        \makebox[\widthof{\faCircle}]{\textcolor{red}{\faCircle}}%
        \stepcounter{trialnumber}\thetrialnumber
    \end{ocg}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\actionsocg{trialstep2}{trialstep1}{trialstep3}{\textcolor{black}{\faCircle}}}%
    \begin{ocg}{trialstep2}{trialstep2}{off}% choice layer
        \makebox[\widthof{\faCircle}]{\textcolor{red}{\faCircle}}%
        \stepcounter{trialnumber}\thetrialnumber
    \end{ocg}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\actionsocg{trialstep3}{trialstep1,trialstep2}{}{\textcolor{black}{\faCircle}}}%
    \begin{ocg}{trialstep3}{trialstep3}{off}% choice layer
        \makebox[\widthof{\faCircle}]{\textcolor{red}{\faCircle}}%
        \stepcounter{trialnumber}\thetrialnumber
    \end{ocg}%
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \askreplymcq__check:nn {ff}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mcqcheck}{ m m }{%
  % Syntax − #1: list of OCG ids of correct/required answer(s), comma separated
  %          #2: list of OCG ids of wrong answer(s), comma separated
  \askreplymcqcheck_process_list:Nn \l_correct_seq { #1 }% Save OCMD IDs as LaTeX3 seq variable
  \askreplymcqcheck_process_list:Nn \l_wrong_seq { #2 }% Save OCMD IDs as LaTeX3 seq variable
  \askreplymcq__check:ff { \seq_use:Nn \l_correct_seq {,} } { \seq_use:Nn \l_wrong_seq {,} }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

%%% reset button

\NewDocumentCommand{\mcqresetcheck}{}{%
  \def\ocglistresetcheck{}%
  \xdef\ocglistresetcheck{%
    \ocglistresetcheck, check.\thequizquestion}%
  \foreach \X in {1,...,\value{mcqquiztotal}} {%
    \xdef\ocglistresetcheck{\ocglistresetcheck, mcqproposalref.\thequizquestion.\X}%
  }%
  \hideocg{\ocglistresetcheck}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[draw] (resetbutton) {\strut Reset};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{quizquestion}{2,4,5}{1,3,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}
  Which are the colour components of an RGB image?\\ Multiple required assertions.\\[8pt]
  \mcqproposal{Magenta.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Green.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Cyan.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Blue.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Red.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Black.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Yellow.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Magenta.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Gray.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Purple.}\\
  \mcqproposal{White.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Pink.}\\
  \mcqproposal{Maroon.}\\[8pt]
\end{quizquestion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is, I  am afraid, the point where JavaScript would need to come into play.

Comment: But let me think about it first, may need some time...

Comment: Your recent, unfortunately deleted question was in fact a good starting point! I very much liked the idea of using `animate` to implement a trials indicator such that I am exploiting it here ;-).

Comment: @AlexG I thought that my other question was too long and not relevant, so I deleted it not to add noise for other users.;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. A little JavaScript is involved too. All logic is put into the "Verify" button, which is the only element whose implementation differs from [(1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492768).

OCGs in a PDF can be accessed and their visibility be set by JavaScript as documented [here](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_jsapiref.pdf#G4.1981789). A simple indicator showing the depletion of available trials is implemented by means of the `animate` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{media9} % \mediabutton
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{wasysym} % \Circle, \CIRCLE
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc} %\widthof{...}

% quiz button
\NewDocumentCommand{\quizButton}{o m m m}{%
  % Syntax − #1: optional: radio button group
  %          #2: button shape: \faCircleThin, \faSquareO
  %          #3: verification id
  %          #4: choice id
  % action on click: toggle myself (choice layer), hide verifcation layer
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\actionsocg{#4}{}{#3}{#2}}%
  \begin{ocg}[\IfValueT{#1}{radiobtngrp=#1}]{#4}{#4}{off}% choice layer
    \makebox[\widthof{#2}]{\textcolor{green!60!black}{\faCheck}}%
  \end{ocg}%
}

% verify button
\NewDocumentCommand{\verifyButton}{m m m}{%
  % Syntax − #1: verification id
  %          #2: list of OCG ids of correct/required answer(s), comma separated
  %          #3: list of OCG ids of wrong answer(s), comma separated
  \mediabutton[jsaction={%
    var ocgs=this.getOCGs(this.pageNum);%
    for(var i=0;i<ocgs.length;i++){%
      if(ocgs[i].name=="#1"&&ocgs[i].state==false&&anim["#1"].frameNum<3){%
        ocgs[i].state=true;%
        anim["#1"].frameNum++;%
      }%
    }%
  }]{\fbox{\strut Verify}}\space%
  \begin{animateinline}[label=#1,nomouse,step]{1}
    \strut\Circle\ \Circle\ \Circle
  \newframe
    \strut\CIRCLE\ \Circle\ \Circle
  \newframe
    \strut\CIRCLE\ \CIRCLE\ \Circle
  \newframe
    \strut\CIRCLE\ \CIRCLE\ \CIRCLE
  \end{animateinline}\quad%
  \begin{ocg}{#1}{#1}{off}% verification layer
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \begin{ocmd}{\Not{\And{#2,\Not{\Or{#3}}}}}% "wrong" layer (OCMD)
        Wrong.
      \end{ocmd}%
    }%  
    \begin{ocmd}{\And{#2,\Not{\Or{#3}}}}% "correct" layer (OCMD)
      Correct.
    \end{ocmd}%
  \end{ocg}%  
}

% reset button
\NewDocumentCommand{\resetButton}{m}{%
  % Syntax − #1: list of OCG ids, comma separated
  \hideocg{#1}{\fbox{\strut Reset}}%
}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

In short, what is the colour of a black cat? One correct answer.\\[8pt]
\quizButton[CatColours]{\faIcon[regular]{circle}}{vrfyCatCol}{red}    The colour is obviously red.\\
\quizButton[CatColours]{\faIcon[regular]{circle}}{vrfyCatCol}{green}  The colour may be green.\\
\quizButton[CatColours]{\faIcon[regular]{circle}}{vrfyCatCol}{black}  The colour is black.\\
\quizButton[CatColours]{\faIcon[regular]{circle}}{vrfyCatCol}{yellow} The colour is undoubtedly yellow.\\[8pt]
\verifyButton{vrfyCatCol}{black}{red,green,yellow}\hspace{0.3\linewidth}
\resetButton{vrfyCatCol,black,red,green,yellow}\\[16pt]

Which are the colour components of an RGB image? Multiple required assertions.\\[8pt]
\quizButton{\faIcon[regular]{square}}{vrfyRGBCol}{magenta} Magenta.\\
\quizButton{\faIcon[regular]{square}}{vrfyRGBCol}{green2}  Green.\\
\quizButton{\faIcon[regular]{square}}{vrfyRGBCol}{cyan}    Cyan.\\
\quizButton{\faIcon[regular]{square}}{vrfyRGBCol}{blue}    Blue.\\
\quizButton{\faIcon[regular]{square}}{vrfyRGBCol}{red2}    Red.\\
\quizButton{\faIcon[regular]{square}}{vrfyRGBCol}{black2}  Black.\\
\quizButton{\faIcon[regular]{square}}{vrfyRGBCol}{yellow2} Yellow.\\[8pt]
\verifyButton{vrfyRGBCol}{red2,green2,blue}{cyan,magenta,yellow2,black2}\hspace{0.3\linewidth}
\resetButton{vrfyRGBCol,red2,green2,blue,cyan,magenta,yellow2,black2}
\end{document}
```