# How to combine a JavaScript code and OCG/OCMG layers within LaTeX source/macro?

Tags: pdf, javascript, ocgx2

This question is a "work in progress" in order to find a solution to the following previous question:

(1) [ocgx2: Multiple Choice Questions up to three automatic trials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586223)

As suggested by @AlexG in a comment, one may have a look to JavaScript. Unfortunately I am a beginner with JavaScript and (La)TeX mixed codes and may be the present question is not well-posed.

Used tools: Linux OS + lualatex (TeXLive 2021) + Okular (which supports JavaScript and OCG/OCMG)

Unused tool: `insdljs` package (it not belongs to TeX Live and has to be installed separately)

Thus, the goal is here to adopt a step by step approach to try to understand what happens:

A. How to include JavaScript code into LaTeX source/macro? For example the following @AlexG's answer works with pdflatex but not with lualatex:

(2) [What is the best way to insert document-level JavaScript in LaTeX documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3080)

B. How to trigger JavaScript code with a button? Is `\mediabutton` from media9 package useful knowing it is only used for that functionality?

C. How to combine OCG/OCMG layers and JavaScript codes within a LaTeX source/macro? e.g. to make calculations and print them.

Besides these issues, could advanced users give me advices about documentation to read? I have remarked the following references, but how to start with and is there another document more relevant?
(a) [Acrobat JavaScript SDK](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/choose.html#javascript)
(b) [Developing Acrobat Applications Using
JavaScript](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_jsdevguide.pdf)
(c) [PDF reference 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)
(d) [LuaTeX doc.](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/doc/luatex)
(e) [PdfTeX doc.](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/doc/pdftex/manual)

Comment: The most important document about Acrobat (Reader) additions to core JavaScript is perhaps the following, listed somewhere below link (a) of your question: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_jsapiref.pdf

Comment: Also, try this combination of tags for searching:[`[hyperref]` `[javascript]` `[forms]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperref+javascript+forms)

Comment: @AlexG Thank you very much for these orientations and tags of searching. One more time helpful ;-)

Comment: The point A./ of the question reflects a lack of culture. One has to simply replace the pdfTeX primitives by the LuaTeX ones: see page 45 of the [LuaTeX documentation.](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/doc/luatex)